# Retornar valor de table

Tags: php

Gostaria de retornar o valor de toda a minha table para um form de alteração ou algo do tipo, quando clicado no meu btn "ver mais", abaixo o print da minha tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu código:**

```html
echo '<form action="vermais.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" >';
echo '<table class="table">';

 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>Protocolo</td>';
 echo '<td>Nome</td>';
 echo '<td>Setor</td>';
 echo '<td>E-mail</td>';
 echo '<td>Prioridade</td>';
 echo '<td>Data cadastrada</td>';
 echo '<td>Status</td>';




 echo '</tr>';

 while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

  $id=$registro['id_status'];
  $st = ("SELECT * FROM status WHERE id=$id");
  $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexao,$st);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
  $s = $row['nome'];

  if("Em analise" == $s){
   $cor="blue";
  }else if("Aprovado" == $s){
   $cor="green";
  }else if("Pendente" == $s){
   $cor = "purple";
  }else{
   $cor = "red";
  }

  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$registro["protocolo"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$registro["nome"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$registro["setor"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$registro["email"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$registro["prioridade"]. '</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$registro["data_cadastro"]. '</td>';
  echo '<td style="color:'.$cor.'">'.$row["nome"].'</td>';
  if($s !='Aprovado'){
   echo '<td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ver mais</button>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';


 }





 echo '</table>'; 

 echo '</form>';
```

Comment: O campo protocolo seria único?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa usar um formulário nessa pagina nem botão submit.

Utiliza o type button e o script `parent.location` passando um parâmetro único:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="parent.location=\'paginaDestino.php?id='.$registro["protocolo"].'\'">Ver mais</button>
```

**HTML**

```
echo '<table class="table">';

echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>Protocolo</td>';
  echo '<td>Nome</td>';
  echo '<td>Setor</td>';
  echo '<td>E-mail</td>';
  echo '<td>Prioridade</td>';
  echo '<td>Data cadastrada</td>';
  echo '<td>Status</td>';
echo '</tr>';

while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    $id=$registro['id_status'];
    $st = ("SELECT * FROM status WHERE id=$id");
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexao,$st);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
    $s = $row['nome'];

    if("Em analise" == $s){
        $cor="blue";
    }else if("Aprovado" == $s){
        $cor="green";
    }else if("Pendente" == $s){
        $cor = "purple";
    }else{
        $cor = "red";
    }

    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$registro["protocolo"].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$registro["nome"].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$registro["setor"].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$registro["email"].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$registro["prioridade"]. '</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$registro["data_cadastro"]. '</td>';
      echo '<td style="color:'.$cor.'">'.$row["nome"].'</td>';
    if($s !='Aprovado'){
        echo '<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="parent.location=\'paginaDestino.php?id='.$registro["protocolo"].'\'">Ver mais</button>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

**Pagina destino -  form de alteração**

```
 $protocolo= $_GET['id'];

 SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE protocolo=$protocolo
```

com isto você monta um formulário para alterar os dados referentes a esse protocolo

```
 <form action= ...... 
 <input .......
 ..............
 <button type="submit" .....
 </form>
```

Comment: Caraca leo, sempre me salvando hahaha. Valeu, deu certinho!!!